# Access 2010 unable to bind recordset to combobox

Tags: combobox, ms-access-2010, ado

**Win7, 64 bit,  Access 2010, ADO 6.1,  App server is Win Server 2008R2**

This is really weird.  The code below works on my local machine but it does not work when I log onto an app server and run the same thing.

```
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command

If cboContractStatus.ListCount <= 1 Then
    Set cmd = getADODBCommand("P_getContractStatus")
    Set cboContractStatusExist.Recordset = rs
    Set cmd = Nothing
End If

If comboAffiliates.ListCount <= 1 Then
    Set cmd = getADODBCommand("B_affGetAllNames")
    Set comboAffiliates.Recordset = cmd.Execute
    Set cmd = Nothing
End If
```

The first combo loads properly.  The second does not load at all.  It gives a msgbox saying "Cannot find column 'Expr 52>'"  It's not really an error at all.  The code doesn't break.  And the msgbox has a link saying "Did this information help?"

Here is the stored proc that is being  called.

```
SELECT
    FirstName + ' ' + LastName affName
FROM
    tbl_Affiliate
ORDER BY
    FirstName
```

One last thing -- as I was coding this yesterday it worked just fine.

Comment: Is `Option Explicit` declared at top of every module, and does the vba compile command succeed?

Comment: One place to start is making your "stored proc" even simpler to see if this isolates the problem: `SELECT FirstName FROM tbl_Affiliate`.  Or, make it identical to the first combo box and then change things until it breaks.

Comment: Yesterday it worked on both machines and today it works on one only?  And you aren't able to see any difference in the code?   I'm thinking there is a difference, if yesterday's code worked.

Comment: Sorry it has taken so long for me to get back to this -- other fires to put out.  Option Explicit is used throughout.  I'll try making the proc simpler although this is just a list of names and is used in many places in the app.  Perhaps I exaggerated with the "yesterday" business.  It was actually the same code -- no changes.  Worked on one machine and not the other.